# Drop Files : delete files in localStorage

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning Javascript on my own and embarking on my first project. I'd like to code a drop file to import images and store them in the localStorage. This part is successful but I want to make a button on each image to be able to delete the image in question in the HTML but also in the localStorage. HTML is ok, but on the second deletion the wrong image is deleted in the localStorage. Do you know how I can ensure that the button isn't based on the image index, but rather on an automatically generated ID?

(sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm a newbie)

```
function stockImg() {
  
  const dropArea = document.getElementById("dropArea");

  // Empêcher le comportement par défaut pour permettre le drop
  dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      dropArea.style.border = "2px dashed #333";
  });

  dropArea.addEventListener("dragleave", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      dropArea.style.border = "2px dashed #ccc";
  });

  dropArea.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropArea.style.border = "2px dashed #ccc";

    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;

    for (const file of files) {
        if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                const imageUrl = event.target.result;

                displayNewImage(imageUrl, imageCount);

                if (localStorage.getItem("images")) {
                    const images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));
                    images.push(imageUrl)
                    localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(images));
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify([imageUrl]));
                }

                imageCount++
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
  });

  // Récupérer les URLs des images du localStorage au chargement de la page
  if (localStorage.getItem("images")) {
      const storedImages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));
      for (let i = 0; i < storedImages.length; i++) {
        displayNewImage(storedImages[i], i)
    }
  }
}

function displayNewImage(image, index) {
  const imageDiv = document.createElement('div')

  imageDiv.classList.toggle('block_img');
  
  const imageTag = document.createElement('img')
  imageTag.src = image
  imageTag.width = 150
  imageTag.height = 150

  const imageBtn = document.createElement('span')
  imageBtn.innerHTML = "<i class='bx bxs-trash' ></i>"
  imageBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      imageDiv.remove()
      const images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));
      images.splice(index, 1)
      localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(images));
  })

  imageDiv.appendChild(imageTag)
  imageDiv.appendChild(imageBtn)
  imageList.appendChild(imageDiv)
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", stockImg);
```

Comment: You can try  by generating a unique Id at the time of image upload or deletion so it will delete correct image from both html & local storage.

To implement the unique ID approach for image deletion. Instead of using the index as the identifier, you have to use the timestamp-based unique ID for each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a unique ID using the generateUniqueId() function for each image that is added to the HTML and localStorage.
When you click on the delete button of an image, it will remove the correct image from both the HTML and localStorage based on the associated unique ID.
With these changes, you should have a more robust solution for handling image deletion without the issues related to index-based deletion.

```
function stockImg() {
  const dropArea = document.getElementById("dropArea");
  const imageList = document.getElementById("imageList");

  let imageCount = 0;

  // Generate a unique ID for each image
  function generateUniqueId() {
    return new Date().getTime().toString();
  }

  // ... Existing code for drag and drop functionality ...

  // Récupérer les URLs des images du localStorage au chargement de la page
  if (localStorage.getItem("images")) {
    const storedImages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));
    for (let i = 0; i < storedImages.length; i++) {
      displayNewImage(storedImages[i], generateUniqueId());
    }
  }
}

function displayNewImage(image, uniqueId) {
  const imageDiv = document.createElement("div");

  imageDiv.classList.toggle("block_img");

  const imageTag = document.createElement("img");
  imageTag.src = image;
  imageTag.width = 150;
  imageTag.height = 150;

  const imageBtn = document.createElement("span");
  imageBtn.innerHTML = "<i class='bx bxs-trash'></i>";
  imageBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    imageDiv.remove();
    const images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));
    const updatedImages = images.filter((img) => img.id !== uniqueId);
    localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(updatedImages));
  });

  imageDiv.appendChild(imageTag);
  imageDiv.appendChild(imageBtn);
  imageList.appendChild(imageDiv);

  // Save the image data to localStorage with the uniqueId as the key
  if (localStorage.getItem("images")) {
    const images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));
    images.push({ id: uniqueId, src: image });
    localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(images));
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify([{ id: uniqueId, src: image }]));
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", stockImg);
```

Comment: Oh great! I've just done the test with a small modification, but the code works perfectly! 
Thanks a lot :D